# How can I update the primary_sale_happened property in Solana NFT, using python?

Tags: python, solana, metaplex

I'm using the Metaplex python-api (https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/python-api) to update an existing NFT.

There is the update_token_metadata function (https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/python-api/blob/441c2ba9be76962d234d7700405358c72ee1b35b/metaplex/transactions.py#L110) that enable changing many of the NFT data - but not the primary_sale_happened property.

I tried to change the update_metadata_instruction_data function, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. the Python API is very outdated. If you are not absolutely limited to using Python you should rather have a look at JS packages or rust crates. There is no public implementation for set_primary_sale_happened in the python API.
2. To set field primary_sale_happened to true a [special instruction](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/instructions#indicate-the-primary-sale-has-happened) has to be called similary to e.g. the authority fields. it cannot be changed through a simple data update.

Metaboss has an [implementation](https://github.com/samuelvanderwaal/metaboss/blob/38a3bf1c3296e59246eae699574efa84d1d54035/src/update_metadata.rs#L415) of how to do it in rust.